# Как сделать определение мата в чате? Discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Я делаю бота модератора чата.
Основная его фишка определение мата в слове и удаление. Я смог сделать и улучшить свой код, однако при тестах возникла проблема которую решить я не в силах. Суть проблемы в том что если мат(допустим слово "тест") пишется с какой-нибудь удвоенной буквы и более ("тееест", "тессссст", "теееесссст"), то бот не может определить мат. Прошу вас помочь мне с моей проблемой:)
`bad_words = "тест|програм|жиз"` #это примеры

```
async def on_message(message):
    await bot.process_commands(message)
    msg = message.content.lower()
    if message.author.guild_permissions.manage_messages is False:
        if re.search(bad_words, msg):
            try:
                await message.delete()
            except:
                await message.channel.send("**Произошла ошибка при удалении! Проверьте наличие прав у бота!**")
            await message.channel.send(f"{message.author.mention} сказал плохое слово!")
```

Comment: Никак. смирись что русские не матреятся, а так разговаривают. Родная речь понимаешь...

Comment: Но всё же, некоторым маты не нравятся

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Создадим список запрещенных слов:**

```
ban_words = ['тест', 'текст']
```

**Добавляем обработчик сообщений:**

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    # если сообщение от какого-либо бота - игнорируем
    if message.author.bot:
        return
```

Внутри функции получаем список отдельных слов сообщения:

```
msg_words = message.content.split()
```

Теперь, когда у нас есть список слов, нужно пробежаться циклом `for` по каждому из них и убрать одинаковые буквы, которые стоят рядом.

Для этого напишем отдельную функцию `simplify_word(word)`, которая будет принимать одно слово и пробегаясь циклом `for` по его буквам оставлять только одну из одинаковых, рядом стоящих:

```
# функция упрощения слова
def simplify_word(word):
    # последняя рассмотренная буква из слова
    last_letter = ''
    # упрощенное слово, без повторяющихся рядом стоящих букв
    result = ''
    
    # пробегаемся по каждой букве слова
    for letter in word:
        # если текущая буква НЕ такая же как и предыдущая, то записываем ее в упрощенное слово
        if letter != last_letter:
            last_letter = letter
            result += letter
    
    return result
```

Теперь вернемся к обработчику сообщений и обработаем каждое слово из сообщения через новую функцию:

```
# упрощаем каждое слово, убирая повторяющиеся, стоящие рядом буквы
for i in range(len(msg_words)):
    msg_words[i] = simplify_word(msg_words[i])
```

Теперь осталось только проверить все, уже обработанные слова сообщения на наличие в списке `ban_words`:

```
# для каждого слова првоеряем, содержится ли оно в запрещенном списке
for word in msg_words:
    if word in ban_words:
        try:
            await message.delete()
        except:
            print('Ошибка при удалении сообщения')
        await message.channel.send(f'{message.author.mention} **написал запрещенное слово:** *{word}*')
        return
```

---

Можем для примера вывести список измененных слов и посмотреть на результат:

```
# вывод упрощенных слов
await message.channel.send(' '.join(msg_words))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Полный код:**

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=discord.Intents.all())

ban_words = ['тест', 'текст']

def simplify_word(word):
    last_letter = ''
    result = ''
    for letter in word:
        if letter != last_letter:
            last_letter = letter
            result += letter
    
    return result

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.bot:
        return

    msg_words = [simplify_word(word) for word in message.content.split()]

    # для каждого слова првоеряем, содержится ли оно в запрещенном списке
    for word in msg_words:
        if word in ban_words:
            try:
                await message.delete()
            except:
                print('Ошибка при удалении сообщения')
            await message.channel.send(f'{message.author.mention} **написал запрещенное слово:** *{word}*')
            return

bot.run('TOKEN')
```

**Не забудьте указать токен!**

Comment: @Harikso если мой ответ решил вашу проблему, могу я попросить вас отметить его как решение? Это даст знать другим пользователям, что проблема решена и можно помочь другим :)