# фильтрация сообщений

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, бот, discord.py

фильтрация сообщений удаляет сообщение, которое содержит только слово находящееся в списке запрещенных, но игнорирует сообщения с целыми предложения с этими же словами.

допустим сообщение

> badword

бот удалит, а сообщение

> это badword

бот проигнорирует

код:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    await client.process_commands( message )

    msg = message.content.lower()

    if msg in (BAD['bad']):
        await message.delete()
        await message.channel.send(f'{message.author.name}, данное сообщение было удалено, т. к. содержит запрещенные слова')
```

Comment: Потому что вы проверяете на совпадение весь текст сообщения, а не **хотя бы одно из слов сообщения**. [**Здесь**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1341325/373173) есть ответ на ваш вопрос, а также как устранить другую проблему - когда слово изменено повторяющимися буквами

Answer (score -2):

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    await client.process_commands( message )

    msg = message.content.lower()
    BAD = {
        'bad': 'badword'
    }
    if BAD['bad'] == msg:
        await message.delete()
        await message.channel.send(f'{message.author.name}, данное сообщение было удалено, т. к. содержит запрещенные слова')
```